# Adding a method to a class using anonymous class

Tags: java, java-8

I'm still rather new to anonymous classes could anyone explain to me why this doesn't work?

```
List<String> instanceOfAnonymousClass = new ArrayList<string>(){
  public void printSomething(){
    System.out.println("something");
  };
};
instanceOfAnonymousClass.printSomething();
```

Eclipse says

> "The method printSomething() is undefined for the type `List<String>`"

So it won't even compile

Comment: You can override methods in an anonymous class, but you can't create new ones.

Comment: Your anonymous class has no class name. Your variable is of type List, and you can't cast it to another type without a class name. Exception to above, you can give it new methods, but they can only be used internally.

Comment: Is there a way I can add a new method to a class without having to create a class inheriting from it? Something like an anonymous class which is way more "disposable"

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks for pointing me to that other question, I've thought of a better way to accomplish my goal now

Comment: Simply create a non anonymous private inner class